# Does reputation degrade over time?

Tags: support, reputation

Over the last few days, my reputation on Stack Overflow has slowly declined from 665 to 659. However, when I look at my reputation page, I only see a single -2 from one of my answers being downvoted; I have apparently lost 4 reputation without any record of where they went or why. Where are the other losses coming from?

Edit: After asking this question I was directed via link to the right to a page that suggested I enable "show removed posts" at the bottom of my reputation page. After clicking on that checkbox, I now have a paper trail for 2 of those missing 4 reputation, but the other 2 remain undocumented. So there are in fact reputation points that are not accounted for even with that option selected.

Comment: Go to your [reputation page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2069424/dimono?tab=reputation) and click on `show removed posts`

Comment: I did; there are still -2 unaccounted for. Editing that into my question now

Comment: You can also check it on http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: At the bottom of your Reputation page is a checkbox to 'show removed posts'. Try that to see if there are any posts deleted that you'd previously earned rep on.

Comment: Do you see the question [hangman game stuff for others to learn from in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15170402/1288) on your reputation report?  You had gained 2 points for an edit, but then it was deleted.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, I saw that. That accounts for 2 of the 4 I'm talking about. There are still 2 unaccounted for

Comment: Hangman game stuff for others to learn from in python!?! Sounds like an _awesome_ question, who deleted that @BilltheLizard? ;P

Comment: @Yannis **deleted by Community♦ 1 hour ago**

Comment: Okay, then I also only see -4 for you in the past couple of days.  Before that there was -30 when a question you answered was deleted and another -2 for a suggested edit on a deleted post, both on March 26.

Comment: @Yannis I can send you the pastebin link if you really want it.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I _really_ don't ;P (but thanks for offering)

Answer (score 2):

No, reputation does not degrade over time. Go to the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069424/dimono?tab=reputation and check "show removed posts". You can also see a detailed report [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) (try using the recalc button at the bottomn, though it's supposed to be obsolete it has been known to fix some quirky edge cases)